# Store views with functions on array in order to show them on tableView

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, view, tableview

I have one class, called CircleView which creates a circle graph with functions that receive parameters. The parameters necessary to create a new graph are:

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphView1: CircleView!

graphView1.animateProgressView(0.3)
graphView1.createLabel(extBar: "iOS", labelText2: "70%", labelColor: .blackColor())
```

I would like to know how can I store some of this graphs, on an array and then show them on a tableView. Is it the best way to show different graphs and texts a tableView?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can, of course, just have an array of CircleViews; var myCircleViews : Array<CircleView> = []  and you can create a view for a table cell based on it.

Comment: And then inside it call these 2 methods? Or how do I create an array of circleViews with circleViews already created? @john-elemans

Comment: Yes, you can create them separately and put them into the array. You can call methods on objects in an array;  myCircleViews[i].animatePorcessView(0.3)

Comment: Will try so, and which is the best way to show some graphs (more than a screen size between all of them) into swift? Create a tableview for them, a pageview or what should be the best?

Comment: I'm not sure of your goal, but a table is, after all, designed to scroll through data too big to fit on one screen.